# Pdf reader with ability to select a text

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp

Do we have some libs which can give me this functionality? Maybe iTextSharp can help? I tried to use Windows.Data.Pdf (UWP) but it just returns an raster image, I can't select a text.
It will be better if the lib is free and supports UWP. Thanks.

Comment: By "select a text" do you mean "extract text"?

Comment: No. When I open pdf in Foxit Reader, Adobe Reader or IE, it provides me ability to select a text.

Comment: Like using click-and-drag with a mouse? So you are looking for a library that provides a PDF viewer component in which you can thusly select text? Shall the text merely be selected in the viewer? Or do you also want to retrieve the text or its position?

Comment: Yes, It will be very good if there is PDF viewer component (I also want to retrieve the selected text).
But I think I can use something like PdfToHtml converter and then I can render it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great lib that works fine for me: http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net

Here is a examplecode for your issue:

```
using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.apache.pdfbox.util;

// ...

private static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
{
  PDDocument doc = null;
  try {
    doc = PDDocument.load(path)
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    return stripper.getText(doc);
  }
  finally {
    if (doc != null) {
      doc.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you integrate it to your project: http://www.squarepdf.net/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-in-net
Its free aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have few questions
1. How I can extract text from the specific page because it contains a lot of page?
2. Can this return other objects (images etc) because I need to render a page (not just retrieve a text)?

Comment: 1.) PDPage doc = document.getPage(pageNum); I think this should work for you. 
2.) As i know there is a way to extract Images just google it .. i never worked with images in pdfs
(Hint: PdfBox is a lib wich was defined in java so you can watch the java api of PdfBox.. works the same for  c#)

Answer (score 1):

I will use `Pdfium` native dll. It has bitmap renderer (`FPDF_RenderPageBitmap_Start`) and retrieve text tools (`FPDFText_GetCharIndexAtPos`, `FPDFText_GetUnicode` etc).

If you do not want work with native lib directly there is a wrapper [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer) but looks like it does not provide select text functionality. You can fork it and extend.

Also there is a lib [Pdfium.Net SDK](https://pdfium.patagames.com/) that provides select text functionality based on Pdfium but it is not a free.

Comment: If you can still remember, Did you figure out how the text selection function works in Pdfium.Net SDK? Did you manage to get it working in PdfiumViewer as well?